# apple push notifications in xcode 5 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

In one of the WWDC sessions they said push notifications would be supported in the simulator with xcode 5. Did this actually happen? I can't see where it works. I see iCloud support but if i try to register device in my app in simulator, it fails.

Comment: Don't think so. I am currently working on different apps with urbanAirship and regular Notifications it isn't working for me.

Comment: Jason, I remember the same statement and got the same error in latest Xcode when I tried to do it. Grrr - yeah - I'm like 100% sure they said it, I saw it again watching an Xcode WWDC video a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

If it does not, there's the SimulatorRemoteNotifications library to fake push notifications in the simulator: https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the Xcode released version 11.4 that supports push notifications:[image]
I did not try yet, but I how it is working.